# Java thrift 0.11 TFramedTransport Exception: Read an invalid frame size

Tags: java, apache, thrift

I am writing a sample client and server using Apache Thrift version 0.11. But when call method from server, it throw an TFramedTransport Exception : ERROR AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer:348 - Read an invalid frame size of -2147418111. Are you using TFramedTransport on the client side?

Here is my client code:

```
 public static ResourceManagerClient getNewClient(String host, int port){
    //create client socket connect to server
    TSocket clientSocket = new TSocket(host, port);
    clientSocket.setTimeout(TIME_OUT);
    //define transport and protocol
    TFramedTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(clientSocket);
    TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(clientSocket);

    ResourceService.Client instance = new ResourceService.Client(protocol);
    ResourceManagerClient client = new ResourceManagerClient(instance, transport);

    return client;
}
```

And Server source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting server ...");
    try{
        //init service processor
        ResourceServiceImp handler = new ResourceServiceImp();
        ResourceService.Processor processor = new ResourceService.Processor(handler);
        //define transport type
        TFramedTransport.Factory transport =  new TFramedTransport.Factory();
        //define protocol
        TBinaryProtocol.Factory protocol = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();         
        // init nonblocking socket server with default address is localhost
        TNonblockingServerSocket socket = new TNonblockingServerSocket(ServerConfig.PORT);
        //init server Args
        THsHaServer.Args serverArgs = new THsHaServer.Args(socket)
                .processor(processor)
                .transportFactory(transport)
                .inputTransportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory())
                .outputTransportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory())
                .protocolFactory(protocol);

        TServer server = new THsHaServer(serverArgs);
        System.out.println("Server is started. Listening on: "+ServerConfig.PORT);
        //start server
        server.serve();

    }catch(TTransportException ex){
        m_logger.error("Can not start server! Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }      
}
```

Exception when i call a method from client:

```
2018-07-25 15:38:01 ERROR AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer:348 - Read an invalid frame size of -2147418111. Are you using TFramedTransport on the client side?
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My miss take is :
 TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(clientSocket);
It should be: 
 TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);

Comment: Is this still a problem? if so, pls share your thrift file, I'll try to recreate.